# In the Vue3 documentation, there is a sentence that I don't quite understand and it doesn't have specific examples to explain it

Tags: events, components, vuejs3

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events

> If a native event (e.g., click) is defined in the emits option, the listener will now only listen to component-emitted click events and no longer respond to native click events.

In the Declaring Emitted Events section, I have not understood this sentence. Can you please provide a specific example to explain it?

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, and I cannot find a specific demo.

Answer (score 2):

This will override native click event for your component.

For exemple, for basic HTML component:

```
<div>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
<script>
  button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    button.innerHTML = `Clics number : ${event.detail}`;

    return event
  });
</script>
```

Normally this kind of event is propagated to the dom and can be intercepted by parent component, like this for example:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')

body.on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  // your code to handle the clicks
});
```

But if you override the method by a vue emit, this will not work anymore:

```
export default defineComponent({
  emit: ['click'],
})
```

The scope of the click is now only at the component level. The only way to catch it is to specify it when you use the component:

```
<my-component @click="myfunction" />
```

Hope it's more clear

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Can you give an example using the options API of Vue3?